# How to flat the tensor in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have a tensor named `words_conv_bigram_pool` which is in the shape of `(?, 1, 1, 64)`, `?` is the batch size.
I try to flatten the tensor to be `(?, 64)` by `Flatten()(words_conv_bigram_pool)`,
but it returns the shape of `(?,?)`.

```
>>> Flatten()(words_conv_bigram_pool)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xuemeng.cyn/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1264: calling reduce_prod (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
<tf.Tensor 'flatten_1/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>
```

What happened and how to use the flatten function in keras?

Comment: Maybe an old keras version? I could not reproduce your error (python: 3.6.4, keras: 2.1.4. tensorflow 1.6.0 os:ubuntu1710)

Comment: my version is 2.1.2.  Let me update it.

Comment: I updated the keras version to 2.1.5 but the problem is still there.

Comment: HM then no idea. Did you try to print keras.__version__? Can't imagine anthing besides an old keras which is somewhere in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't care much about "tensorflow shapes", care about "keras shapes". It's common to see such `?` tensorflow dimensions when you're using keras.

If you add this flatten layer to your model and then do a `model.summary()`, you will see the desired shape.

If you're not using a "keras model", but only want to remove the additional dimensions, you can try [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze).